# How to change properties of holes?

Tags: eaglecad

I'm very new to Eagle so please bare with me. I'm hoping to check and change the properties of the holes on a PCB, but I can't seem to right click them. I've removed all layers except for the hole and drill ones.

[image]

The biggest issue is that, after converting to gerber, the drill file blows up the area by almost 100x (from 0.5in^2 to 70in^2), so I wonder if my holes are problematic.

Thanks

Comment: Are these holes part of a part or did you place them individually yourself?

Comment: I believe they were placed individually. These are holes on a breakout board designed by someone else which I found online. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ad8sldcsk3a2zid/hm11.brd?dl=0

Comment: I looked at the board. Each vertical row of holes is part of part.

Comment: I see. If I display the converted Gerber with the drill files, the area gets blown up to 70in^2 using http://mayhewlabs.com/webGerber/ Is there a way to fix the drill files? Do the holes need fixing?

Comment: The problem must be with the way you are generating the gerber files. I generated a set of gerber files using the provided board file and viewed them using the suggested site. They displayed just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe my issue is related to resolution. In eagle.def, under [EXCELLON], I divided the values of `ResX` and `ResY` by 10. I'm not sure why EXCELLON_24 uses 10000 whilst EXCELLON uses 100000 by default though.

However, I'm not sure if it's right to just change the resolution of Excellon - perhaps Excellon 24 is more appropriate. Choosing EXCELLON_24 also produces (seemingly) good results.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in the comments the Gerber files generated and displayed with no problem. There must be a problem with the way you are generating them. Watch this video.
http://eapbg.com/2015/08/13/eapbg-2-impromptu-eagle-board-layout/
At the very end of the video I go over how to generate Gerber files. Also there is a link to the job file i used.

Comment: Do you mean you have no problems with the drill files as well? That is, the area doesn't get blown up to 70in^2 with the drill files imported using mayhewlabs.com/webGerber ? For me, the Gerber files show up fine, except when the drill files are imported.

Comment: I believe I've fixed my issue now.

Comment: Correct, the board was displayed with the drill file with no problems.

Comment: I've followed your video and uses the job from OSH Park but to no avail. Did you use EXCELLON 24 though?

Comment: That job file generates the EXCELLON files. Did you generate your own?

Comment: I tried both 2 layer and 2 layer 7.2 (though I'm on 7.3). I didn't change any setting and just went with the defaults. IIRC, the OSHP job file defaults to EXCELLON. I have mine fixed by using the Eagle excellon job and selecting EXCELLON 24 instead.